# A DIY SWR bridge and some problems (toroids, diodes, etc.)

Tags: ham-radio, swr-meter

First of all, I've been a licensed radio amateur for 2-3 months. I want to make an SWR bridge myself that will work in the HF band. I want to use the MFJ 945E SWR bridge circuit as I don't have enough knowledge but I have a few problems.

I cannot find a finished PCB to make this circuit. After all, it's always good to do it ready-made for a novice. How can I draw the circuit? This is my most important and critical issue. Can you help me with this?

I think a T30-2 toroid used in this circuit. I want this toroid not to get hot at high power. When it gets hot, it will lose its toroid feature. Can I use a T37-2 or T50-6 toroid?

For my third question, let's say I used a T37-2 toroid.  Should I wind it like in the MFJ 945E?

It's worth adding a few things.

1. I took a toroid out of a bulb that I was thinking of using. I think T30-2 is a toroid. Can I use this toroid? I will also share pictures.
2. The winding on the toroid is 15 turns and a flat winding. There is also a common end at the midpoint. I have reviewed the MFJ-945E and these are my conclusions.
3. As I mentioned above, toroids lose their magnetic properties as they heat up. I do not want this, I want it to be able to withstand 1kW power. If I use a different toroid, do I need to change the winding or is it okay if I use a 15-turn winding again?
4. What I want to do is a Bruene bridge that can withstand 1kW power between 1-50 MHz.

Here are some pictures:

Toroid:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Schematic:

[image: schematics]

Comment: You might try asking this on https://ham.stackexchange.com/ While there might be people here that can help, the ham stackexchange is going to more specialized to what you are asking about.

Comment: What's an SWR bridge?